# HTMLAgilityPack and Trouble Returning Full Table

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm working with some html tables and trying to dig through them with htmlagilitypack. The source html is found here: https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?title=breaking+benjamin+polyamorous&type%5B1%5D=200&rating%5B0%5D=4&rating%5B1%5D=5
Sample table:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" class="tresults">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="175">Artist :</th>
      <th>Song :</th>
      <th width="115">Rating :</th>
      <th width="80">Type :</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/tabs/breaking_benjamin_tabs.htm" class="song search_art">
          <b>Breaking</b>  <b>Benjamin</b> 
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://plus.ultimate-guitar.com/tp/?artist=Breaking+Benjamin&amp;song=Polyamorous" class="song js-tp_link"><b>Polyamorous</b></a>
        <a target="_blank" class="js-tp_link" href="http://plus.ultimate-guitar.com/tp/?artist=Breaking+Benjamin&amp;song=Polyamorous"><b 
class="play_tab_list"title="Playback"></b></a>
      </td>



      <td class="gray4"></td>
      <td><strong>tab pro</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="stripe">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver2_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 2)</a>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_4"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">5</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver4_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 4)</a>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_4"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">30</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="stripe">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver5_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 5)</a>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_4"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">12</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver6_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 6)</a>
        &nbsp;
        <span rel="#info_333408" class="tabinfo">info</span>
        <div class="dn" id="info_333408">
          <font style="font-family:trebuchet ms;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%"><b><font color="#DDDDCC">+</font> Difficulty:</b> <font color="#DDDDCC">novice</font>
          <br>
          </font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_4"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">20</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="stripe">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver7_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 7)</a>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_4"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">5</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_ver8_tab_952279id_24052010date.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b> (ver 8)</a>
        &nbsp;
        <span rel="#info_952279" class="tabinfo">info</span>
        <div class="dn" id="info_952279">
          <font style="font-family:trebuchet ms;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%"><b><font color="#DDDDCC">+</font> Difficulty:</b> <font color="#DDDDCC">novice</font>
          <br>
          </font>
          <p style="margin-top:3px"><font style="font-family:trebuchet ms;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%"><b><font color="#DDDDCC">+</font> Tuning:</b> <font color="#DDDDCC">Drop C#</font></font>
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_5"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">6</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="stripe">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/breaking_benjamin/polyamorous_acoustic_tab.htm" class="song result-link"><b>Polyamorous</b>&nbsp;Acoustic</a>
        &nbsp;
        <span rel="#info_258880" class="tabinfo">info</span>
        <div class="dn" id="info_258880">
          <font style="font-family:trebuchet ms;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%"><b><font color="#DDDDCC">+</font> Difficulty:</b> <font color="#DDDDCC">novice</font>
          <br>
          </font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="gray4"><span class="rating"><span class="r_5"></span></span> <span>[ <b class="ratdig">9</b> ]</span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>tab</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In order to grab this table from the full html doc, here is a snippet of my C# code:

```
string source_code = web.DownloadString("https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?title="+ songArtist + songTitle + "&type%5B1%5D=200&rating%5B0%5D=4&rating%5B1%5D=5");
doc.LoadHtml(source_code);    
HtmlNodeCollection resultsTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='tresults']");
            foreach(var cell in resultsTable.Descendants())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerHtml);
            }
```

I am expecting to have the full contents of the table returned, except it stops at the line: `<b class="play_tab_list" title="Playback"></b>`

My ultimate goal is to return all of the links in the table, but I cannot even get as far as to see the full table.

Comment: if you select a single node, you shouldn't expect to get a collection but a node if exist.

Comment: I didn't get any error while parsing the document. Please check that the version of Agility you're using is compatible with your Microsoft framework. Also if you're getting this html from the web, make sure the encoding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will print the url for all links on the table.

```
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        var web = new WebClient();
        string source_code = web.DownloadString("https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?title=breaking+benjamin+polyamorous&type[1]=200&rating[0]=4&rating[1]=5");
        doc.LoadHtml(source_code);
        HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@class,'link')]");
        foreach (var link in links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", link.InnerText, link.Attributes["href"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: Using the code that you have above works as expected. Now I am wondering if the source html code that I am grabbing could be formatted incorrectly? This is the full source of the html: view-source:https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/search.php?title=breaking+benjamin+polyamorous&type%5B1%5D=200&rating%5B0%5D=4&rating%5B1%5D=5

Comment: Your revised code is not returning the full table anymore. It is only returning the first two links as shown here: Breaking Benjamin              /tabs/breaking_benjamin_tabs.htm
Polyamorous http://plus.ultimate-guitar.com/tp/?artist=Breaking+Benjamin&song=Polyamorous
 http://plus.ultimate-guitar.com/tp/?artist=Breaking+Benjamin&song=Polyamorous    This is further causing me to think there is something wrong with the source formatting? The same html data works as intended if it is first ran through an html "tidier" such as http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: AgilityPack fails to parse the document because html downloaded is not syntactically correct. The html code you posted does not reproduce the error because it's correct.

Comment: So would some sort of regex searching be the way to deal with this html?

Comment: Agility was closing the table after finding malformed html (double </td> instead of one). For that reason only some links appear to belong to table tresults. So yes, you can either use regex of just change the xpath for not to rely on the table for finding links. I have edited the code. Now it's targeting links with a class that contains the word "link". Hopefully it won't be too broad.

Comment: The new fix - targeting classes that contain the work "link" - works perfectly! It's a relief to find out that the error was due to bad html. Thanks!